# What happens if an EU software company violates an EU software patent?

Tags: patents

What happens if an EU company develops an Android App and that App and a US company claims that the App violates a patent that the company filled in the US?

Is the EU company in the clear as long as the don't violate an EU patent?

Comment: Do you plan on selling this app in Google Play Store? Do you plan on selling this app to US-based customers?

Comment: @Thebluefish : Preferably yes.